# Confidence interval of the panel data model

Tags: confidence-interval, panel-data, tobit-regression

I have a panel of $m$ individuals over $n$ periods of time. I am estimating decision making rules of people $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X + ...+\epsilon$. I have reasons to believe that $\beta_1$ are very similar across population, while $\beta_0$ might differ by individuals. Since the data is censored, I am using tobit with individual random effects for intercepts. Now, I want to confirm my intuition about $\beta_1$ being similar for all individuals. This is what was suggested.

First, I estimate $\beta_1$ using pooled data as described above. Second, I estimate $n$ models at the individual level and get a sample of $n$ individual level $\hat\beta_1$. Third, I calculate its mean and SD, and compute 95% C.I. using $\hat\beta_1^{mean}\pm Z \frac{S_{\hat\beta_1}}{\sqrt{n}}$ assuming normally distributed $\hat\beta_1$ across population. Now, if the pooled estimation (from the first regression) of $\beta_1$ falls within this C.I., I can conclude that my first pooled model provides a good estimation at the 95% confidence level of the "true" population level $\beta_1$.

Does this make sense or is there a better way to do it?